# Determine the type of source device from youtube video metadata

Tags: youtube-api

I was wondering if there is any way to determine from youtube video metadata the type of device (general category such as -> mobile, webcam,handycam,etc.) using which the video was shot.

Thanks

JR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to retrieve this information from the youtube apis.

It's not a great solution, but depending on the specific problem you are trying to solve you could try looking in the video's tags (or even description) for things like "mobile", "webcam", "handycam", etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply Matt. Yes seems like it. Since there is no camera file metadata, looks like it is not quite possible.